# How do I change the style of the frame lines in a radar(polar) chart created with highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, radar-chart

I am looking for settings to change some of the frame-lines in the radar chart.

There are 3 types of lines I'd like to be customized:

1. The red triangle line outside.
2. The 3 blue lines from center to each corner.
3. The small green triangle.

I've searched a lot but totally had no clue. I have tried to change the `lineWidth` of the `yAxis` and it only changes the width of the upper vertical line.

[image]

Here below is the code. It uses the latest highcharts to render the chart, as of *Sep 12 2021* when I'm writing this question, it's `9.2.2`:

```js
window.chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    polar: true,
    type: 'area'
  },
  title: {
    text: "radar chart title",
    margin:33,
    useHTML:true
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}"><b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    animation:true
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["a","b","c"],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 4,
    min: 0,
    max:100
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: "Haha",
    animation:true,
    data: [52,119, 12],
    lineWidth:4
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use plot lines for y-axis:

   ```
   yAxis: {
       ...
       plotLines: [{
           color: 'red',
           value: 100,
           zIndex: 2
       }]
   }
   ```
2. Use `gridLineColor` for x-axis:

   ```
   xAxis: {
       ...,
       gridLineColor: 'blue'
   }
   ```
3. Use `gridLineColor` for y-axis:

   ```
   yAxis: {
       gridLineColor: 'green',
       ...
   }
   ```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fm45ab3k/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotLines

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have tried many times but can't make the red line and green line go their own way separately: http://jsfiddle.net/3ofqh5wr/ The inner triangle has red+green lines together.

Is there any way to make them behavior different on each own's style? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AGamePlayer, You can use only plot lines. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7hmdqkgu/